# Fixing style of footer overlapping body

Tags: html, css

I have created a footer but it is overlapping body. this is the image.
[image]

```css
/*Start section links*/
.links .back-color {
    background: #fafafa;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.links .line h2 {width: 196px}

.links .line ul {display: inline;padding-left: 30px;}
.links .line ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    line-height: 32px;
}
.links .line ul li.last {border-right: none}
.links .line h2 {
    width: 196px;
    height: 33px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 99%;
    min-width: 120px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;margin: 0 20px 1px 0;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}
.links .line h2:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -24px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 19px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left: 24px solid #fe9c00;
}
.links .line .title1 {background: #0050A0 }
.links .line .title2 {background: #0050A0; }
.links .line .title2:before {border-left: 24px solid #0050A0;}


.footer {padding: 22px 0 20px 0;}
.footer .designed-by a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <!-- Start section about-->
 <section class="footer-body">
  <section class="links">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="back-color">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="line">
        <h2 class="title2">
        <span>Our mission</span>
        </h2>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <li>
          <p>Our mission is to provide buyers a platform to find their desired products amongst various shops. And to provide a platform to shop owners to manage their shops and inventory without any hassle.</p></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="line">
        <h2 class="title2">
        <span>Information </span>
        </h2>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <br />
         <br />
         <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
         <br />
        </ul>
       </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
       <div class="line">
        <h2 class="title2">
        <span>Request </span>
        </h2>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <br />
         <br />
         <li><a href="#">report</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">request a feature</a></li>
         
        </ul>
       </div>

      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </section>
 <!-- End section about-->
</footer>
```

I have tried to add `position: fixed` but it didn't work. Can anyone please tell me how to fix the footer at the bottom of the page. I mean it doesn't matter how long the body be, footer will always remain the same and at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two options you can do with it, One is you should add a another line of code along with position:fixed as follows,

```
.footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

And second one is, if u want the footer to move bottom after the content, you need to set some minimum height to your content..

Answer (score 1):

`footer` is a `html tag` and you have used it as a `class` for `styling` which actually is not declared, instead style it as a `tag` and use `position` as `fixed` along-with `bottom` as `zero` to align footer at bottom of page as below,

```
footer{
  padding: 22px 0 20px 0;
  background:red;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this

```
.footer{
   position:relative;
   bottom:0px;//Or different value to stick in the bottom
}
```

or
give `margin-top` for the footer, so it won't overlab

addition to that, make sure your page content is wrap inside a div. This issue can be caused due to the position attributes in your page contents, so keep them in separate div might help you.